# Hooking method return crash in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, hook, theos

There is a method I'm trying to hook it but the hooked app crashed , so this is the method:

`+ (id)newFromData:(id)arg1;`

the original return is a json string like {"Name":"Sam"...etc}.
That's what i've tried :

```
%hook ClassName
+ (id)newFromData:(id)arg1 {
NSString *jsonString = "My Modified JSON String!"
NSData *returnData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;

id restaurantsObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:0 error:nil];
return restaurantsObjects;
}
%end
```

It success in compile but app still crashed.

Comment: where is the crash and what does the debugger tell you about it?That would be helpful for answering.

Comment: Why do you create `jsonParsingError` if then you don't use it? Try `id restaurantsObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:0 error: jsonParsingError];` And then it should return something like this `return jsonParsingError ? nil : restaurantsObjects;`

Comment: @volker The App crashed and exit I'm talking about ios app.

Comment: @PabloA. it still crashed , i ganna be crazy :(